# Call main function to restart application

Tags: c#, service

I have a application that needs to run all day but sometimes it gives a exception and then the application crashes. If that happends the devices connected to the application cannot do their work.

What I need to do is restart the application when I crashes but I dont want to make another program to do that.

This is what is what I think I need to do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                ServiceBase.Run(new WebDaemonService(HttpClass.StartListening));
            }
            else
            {
                HttpClass.StartListening();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Restart();
        }               
    }
```

But how do I make a restart function, do I just call the main class again or do I need to do something else.

The if else in the try is to check if the application needs to start as a windows service or as a application.

Can someone explain to me how I can make a restart function?

Comment: You should try handling/fixing the exception instead... catching the exception as part of your programs flow isn't a great way to do things

Comment: @SayseHow can i to that so the application will run again

Comment: I have no idea, you haven't said what the exception *is*

Comment: The use of ServiceBase.Run(..) indicates that it can run as a Windows Service ? - Under Computer Management => Services and Applications => Services => <your service>. Look at the tab "Recovery". Where you can take actions it the program fails

Comment: @togocoder thanks for the tip i will look into righyt now.

Comment: This is the exception: An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection

Comment: @CKY I think you're asking the wrong question. Seems like you're already working on a workaround while you could have asked a question to solve the real problem. Restarting the program is only a last resort solution which I think is not needed.

Comment: Yes the problem is that when the application crashes i need to start it manualy. I want the application to do it by itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event handler on ProcessExit event of current domain.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit
```

[See doc at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Restart you application or service from there. If this is windows service, you can set it to restart on crashes from Services.msc window also.

Code sample:

```
class Foo
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit); 
       // Do your stuffs
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "Full path of exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "arguments";
        p.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i understand that, but how can i start my application and where do i need to do this?

Comment: So `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit); ` will be above my code? that i already have?

Comment: It should be at that line which must get called once. So if you make it as first statement of Main(), it would be called before any crashes occur in program.

Comment: Please read the documentation and its remarks carefully. do not perform much task in CurrentDomain_ProcessExit()